# Page to display on start of application

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hello guys and welcome to the next episode of *New to React so lets experiment*! In this episode we present:

Trying display the `Home` component on application start.

I went with building the homepage in a different component, not sure if this is the right approach but I thought it would be nice to keep the `App.js` clean from all the `html` and such.

Doing this though, causes a problem it seems, as it does not seem to show the `Home` component on app boot (duh), instead it just displays a black page. In order to get to the *hompage* you need to click the navbar brand link in the `Navigation` since I've added a link for that.

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="App">
                    <Navigation />
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h1>Some content</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                            <Route path="/page1" component={page1} />
                            <Route path="/page2" component={page2} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

I think I could use a `<Redirect>` to redirect to the `Home` component but this seems like a workaround to me, rather than what should actually happen.

What would be a better way of doing this?

Comment: Isn't the `homepage component` the one named `Home` in your code?

Comment: Yes, I accepted the edit, thank you for improving the question :)

Comment: This looks ok. Show your `Home` component. Any errors? You could also test router mechanism via `<Route exact path="/" render={() => alert("home")} />`

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, `Home` component didn't show any errors, for some reason `"/"` didn't seem to want to work, even though it did in other cases, so while starting at the `url` I just though to remove the _/_ from `path` and try like that. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Never mind, you can't navigate the other links if you do this, it does render the `Home` component once you enter the application, but when clicking on links to navigate somewhere else, it doesn't work. I was ahead of myself, didn't do some more testing :)